# Why can't a list be defined like this in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
[(a,b) | a <- [1..5], b <- [1..5], a+b <- [1..10] ]
```

Trying to define define a list that follows these rules.  I know it doesn't allow the way I am adding a and b but I don't understand why.

Edited forgot the "<-"

Comment: What do you expect the expression `a+b [1..10]` to mean? Perhaps you're missing some operator or function relating `a+b` with `[1..10]`?

Comment: And it's still not clear what you actually want the result to be. Could you please tell us? It looks like you mean `[(1,1),(1,2)...(1,5),(2,1)...(5,4),(5,5)]`, but that's just what you already get with just `[(a,b) | a <- [1..5], b <- [1..5]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
[(a,b) | a <- [1..5], b <- [1..5], a + b >= 1 && a + b <= 10]
```

Or this?

```
[(a,b) | a <- [1..5], b <- [1..5], a + b `elem` [1..10]]
```

Haskell doesn't solve equations for you, it performs calculations.

This declares the values which a variable takes:

```
a <- [1..5]
```

This is a request for Haskell to solve an equation, which it doesn't do... the left side has to be a valid pattern.

```
a + b <- [1..10] # Not valid Haskell
```

Of course, patterns can be more sophisticated,

```
> [a | Just a <- [Just 10, Nothing, Just 20]]
[10, 20]
```

Comment: That's i think the second is what i am looking for

Comment: The second one is much slower than the first, and they're equivalent.

Comment: How can it not be between 1 and 10? Also, what about `[(a,b) | a <- [1..n], b <- [1..10-a]]` in general?

Comment: @luqui Not always. Consider fix id

Comment: @luqui: Even systems of fixed point equations. :-) Though, this information does not help understanding the original question.

Comment: @FUZxxl, at the risk of taking my original joke way too seriously: `_|_` is certainly a fixed point of `id`, is it not?

Comment: well, Haskell kinda solves typing problems. This can go a little ways into determining the behavior of a program. (e.g. if having the type system choose an instance does significantly different things.)

Answer (score 3):

The "<-" in a list comprehension *actually* draws elements from a list.
Your third expression, "a+b <- [1..10]" is really trying to express that the sum *could* be drawn from a list. That's a job for `(elem)`, a predicate, or test.

```
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

A pretty good way to think about the problem is, how would it be implemented? You'd have to take elements, *then* test to see if they met the criteria. I'd use a predicate like

```
elem (a + b) [1..10]
```

to test that.